# Convert given timestamp to a current time in particular time zone

Tags: php

What are your solutions of making timestamp comparable with time in particular time zone (get real difference between time saved as timestamp and curruent time) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you keep your timestamps in integer form, you can just save the output from time() which is the unix epoch value, which is based on UTC.  This makes time zone irrelevant, so you can always subtract the two values to get the difference in seconds.

```
$t1 = time();
```

//    ... later ...

```
$t2 = time();
$timeDiff = $t2 - $t1;
echo "The difference is " . $timeDiff . " seconds.";
```

Comment: I have read "Local time as string can be get by strftime() and local timestamp (if ever needed) by mktime().", although my mktime() - time() is 0 ?

Comment: Make sure your server (specifically your php.ini file) is set to your desired time zone if you plan on using specific time zones instead of UTC.  I say this just as an aside because I was trying the same thing and couldn't find out for the longest time why my time was different than what the server was showing (sad, but true).

Answer (score 1):

I agree with answer from btx. In order to get better understanding of time zones, UTC and other time related issues, you may read [this article](http://www.odi.ch/prog/design/datetime.php) Although it is mainly related to Java, main concepts that are not programming language specific are described there.